# Turn PHP variable into Javascript variable and use that Javascript variable as an argument in a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, html, variables

An input from a form in my index.php page is sent to my search.php page. This input is turned into the PHP variable $q with $_GET. How do I turn this PHP variable into a Javascript variable that is a string? Then how do I pass this string as an argument in a Javascript function in the body tag when the page loads? The onload function only works if the first parameter is a string. Here is my simplified code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET["q"])) {
    $q = $_GET["q"];
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="assets/js/script.js">
     var q = "<?php echo $q;?>";
 </script>
</head>

<body onload="return Search(*PHP variable turned into Javascript string*, otherFunction(), otherFunction2())">

    <div>
    Content
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the content of your assets/js/script.js file? is that the var q = "<?php echo $q;?>";?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The script doesn't work because you're trying to include an external JavaScript file, while also using the same tag for inline script.

**This part**

```html
<script src="assets/js/script.js">
    var q = "<?php echo $q;?>";
</script>
```

**Should look something like this**

```html
<script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
<script>
    var q = "<?php echo $q;?>";
</script>
```

**Fully fixed code**

```php
<?php

if(isset($_GET["q"])) {
    $q = $_GET["q"];
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
    <script>
        var q = "<?php echo $q;?>";
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="return Search(q, otherFunction(), otherFunction2())">

    <div>
    Content
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Edit: Footnote**

As [@dossy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52617293/10400050) points out, you should avoid directly passing user input into the HTML code. Use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to avoid any malicious code or invalid input.

```html
<script>
    var q = <?php echo json_encode($q); ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: This fixed the problem. Thank you so much! :D

Answer (score 0):

Javascript within your script tag 'should' be ignored if there's a src for it. However you can't have precompiled php in a js file. One option is to set the javascript variables within your php files, then separately include your js files. If your js files make use of those variables, make sure to set the variables first:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var q = "<?php echo $q;?>";
</script>
<script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what `json_encode()` is for.  Other answers that use the naive approach of `var x = "<?php echo $var; ?>";` will break if `$var` contains a double quote, for example.

This is the safest way of doing this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var q = <?php echo json_encode($q); ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: While this is good practice to keep in mind, it's not what caused the issue for the OP. There's no need to downvote other answers for it, just write a comment on the answers that lack it.

Comment: @Johan Considering the danger of emitting the contents of a PHP variable unencoded into a `<script>` element, any answer that suggests doing it should be downvoted because it's not just "good practice" but `json_encode()` is the only safe way to do it.  It is dangerous to continue to propagate unsafe answers that others will find and use.

Comment: I believe that [answers that solves the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) should be upvoted and those who obfuscate or gives blatantly wrong solutions should be downvoted. In the scope of the question, `json_encode()` is just a small detail that the OP probably didn't know he needed, or didn't include to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). However, for the sake of security I've since yesterday edited my question to include`json_encode()` and credited you, if you care for removing your downvote.

Comment: Also, a bit of advice: When downvoting an answer because you think it lacks something or isn't a safe practice, comment and explain why so the author of the answer understands why and so answer can be improved :)

Comment: I think there's a big difference between answers that differ in matters of opinion, vs. answers that are outright dangerous if people do what they say.  If you remove the dangerous portion of your answer, I'd be happy to remove my downvote - otherwise, I downvote any answer that I don't think other people should treat as correct.

Comment: If you ever want to have fun, go to GitHub and search PHP projects for `<script>` and `<?php echo $` ... :)